# Vulnerable Components CVSS Score

Tags: vulnerability, cve, cvss

How do you map vulnerable components' CVSS scores?
Do you use the CVE CVSS score? Do you calculate again?

For example: A host is using a component that has a CVE for a high vulnerability.

Do you report it as a HIGH vulnerability (like the CVE) or do you take another approach?

Comment: Do you mean how to calculate the CVE of the whole system when a component has a CVE?

Comment: I want to know how people go about calculating CVSS for components with known vulnerabilities (CVEs) but that's not active. Meaning we can't explore it but it has this CVE

Comment: This is still difficult to understand. "Not active"? What does that mean? "We can't explore it"? I think you are going to need to provide an example.

Comment: Not active meaning you can't exploit the vulnerability.
For example: PHP 7.0 was detected which is affected by CVE-2019-9641. The CVE CVSS score is 7.5 (https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-9641/) but we can't exploit this vulnerability

Comment: The question is meaningless. CVSS does not claim to support any inheritance or transfer of scores. The only way to make a report would be "a component of this host has a CVE with a CVSS score of n".

Answer (score 0):

CVSS scores aren't calculated based on if something is active or not active. If a version of software has a vulnerability, it doesn't go away just because you can't exploit it yourself. The way CVSS works is on a scale that ranges from zero to 10 that depend on a variety of factors. These factors include exploitabilty metrics (access vector, complexity of the attack, and the authentication needed), impact metrics (confidentiality, availability, integrity), and temporal metrics (exploitability, remediation level, report confidence). The scores are based off how easy it is to exploit, the kind of authentication being used to protect it, and the ease of access (ie directly from the internet, or having to sit in front of the machine).

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss/v2-calculator

Back to your original question, the overall score would be the exact same because while your system may be an exception if this vulnerability is unexploitable for you guys, the vast majority of systems are still vulnerable. CVEs are also based off of scientific research and repeated under a variety of conditions to determine how it should be scored.

Adding to this:
For reporting software with a high vulnerability, if you believe it won't be exploited, justify it to your supervisor or at least inform him of what's going on, then create a memorandum or some kind of documentation that the risk has been assessed for this vulnerability and the system in question is not at risk of exploitation by this CVE, therefore accepting that risk